# Creating 3d surface plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data file with 2,000,000 data points in it of the form (x,y,z) and am trying to make a surface map of the info to go into a paper. The graph it ends up giving me looks to have maybe 10 data points in it instead of the full potential energy surface I need. What do I need to do to get a better graph.

Here is my code:

```
with open("surfaceinfo.dat", "rb") as f:
    CN_data = pickle.load(f)
    CC_data = pickle.load(f)
    energy = pickle.load(f)

plotx,ploty, = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(CN_data),np.max(CN_data),10),
                           np.linspace(np.min(CC_data),np.max(CC_data),10))
plotz = interp.griddata((CN_data,CC_data),energy(plotx,ploty),method='linear')
plotz = np.nan_to_num(plotz)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

colormap = plt.cm.bwr
surf = ax.plot_surface(plotx,ploty,plotz,cmap=colormap,linewidth=0,antialiased=False)

fig.colorbar(surf)

plt.savefig('mapping40,000')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the shape of `CN_data`, `CC_data` , and `energy(plotx,ploty)`?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of linspace function is the number of points that you want. In your code this value is 10. So your surface will have 10x10 points.  Change that argument to set the number of points on your surface.